# HTML/JS speedtest (download, upload and latency)

Tags: open-source, web-apps, connection-speed

We are looking for an open source project to measure

- download speed
- upload speed
- ping

and display the data in a nice fashion.

The testing should be done over the internet with our server and not contact any other server. The server technology is limited to Apache with Java and PHP.

A perfect example would be: http://speedof.me/

Answer (score 1):

[Python](http://python.org) has tools to perform just about any data transfers that you can imagine in the various URL libraries and the timeit tool is very handy for timing operations.  You can then select from a wide range of data visualization tools to display the data, trends, etc. I would suggest taking looks at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) and at [plot.ly](https://plot.ly/) for that.

Answer (score 0):

The nicest application I could find is this one:

http://speedtest.fdossena.com/ -  source code is up on their github repository.

And this is an alternative: https://github.com/beradrian/jsbandwidth